# How to add mobile number validater in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

def validate_mobile_number(value):
if not str(value).isdigit():
raise ValidationError("Please Enter Valid Mobile Number")
class ModelA(AbstractUser):
mobile = models.CharField(_("Mobile"), unique=True, max_length=10,validators[validate_mobile_number,validators.MinLengthValidator(limit_value=10)])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using it with a template and ModalForm, you can add a 'clean_mobile' function to validate the mobile.

```
class ModalAForm(form.ModalForm):
    class Meta:
        modal = ModalA
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        if not mobile.isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please Enter Valid Mobile Number')
        return mobile
```

or else if you're using it with api calls, you can add the same in modalserializer class with function name 'validate_mobile' like

```
def validate_mobile(self, value):
    if not value.isdigit():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Please Enter Valid Mobile Number')
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_mobile_number(value):
   if not str(value).isdigit():
     raise ValidationError("Please Enter Valid Mobile Number")
        
class ModelA(AbstractUser):     
   mobile = models.CharField(_("Mobile"), unique=True, max_length=10, 
                   validators[validate_mobile_number, 
                   validators.MinLengthValidator(limit_value=10)])
```